# How to find the nth word of a string C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying find the nth word of a string. How do I do that using C#? I have tried splitting in spaces after that I don't know how to check each word.

Comment: `postSplit[n]`?

Comment: After you use the split() function an array is returned with number of elements = number of words that the string has been split into. The split occurs in the same order

Comment: @itsme86, its not clear.

Comment: `inputString.Split(' ')[n - 1]` will return the `nth` word, or throw an `IndexOutOfRange` exception if there are fewer than `n` words in `inputString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for spaces in the string and split. and string array from those segments. After that pass index to get the array item.
You can find the explanation here. Question number 12.
http://xcelitsolutions.co.uk/JustCode/CSharp/AllQuestions.php?Chapter=Strings

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the String");
string text = Console.ReadLine();//Enter the string
Console.WriteLine("Enter which word to show");//location of the word
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
char[] mychar = {' '};
string[] wordslist = text.Split(mychar);
Console.WriteLine(wordslist[number-1]);
```

Comment: _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_.  Perhaps borderline - _[your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Consider editing your answer to contain a summary of the article pointed to by the link.

Answer (score 0):

After you use the split() function an array is returned with number of elements = number of words that the string has been split into. The split occurs in the same order. Simply call the index of the word you want.

```
string phrase = "The quick brown    fox     jumps over the lazy dog.";
string[] words = phrase.Split(' ');
Console.Writeline(words[5]); // prints 'over'
```

Comment: _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_